# Command-line JMX Client set value

Tags: java, activemq-classic, jmx

I m using [Command-line JMX Client](http://crawler.archive.org/cmdline-jmxclient/) to be able to query ActiveMQ Server. At the same time I want to be able to set values dynamically to the server. such as **MemoryLimit**.

Is it possible to set values via Command-Line JMX client, if yes , how can i set the memory limit?

This is how i was able to query.

```
java -jar cmdline-jmxclient-0.10.3.jar - localhost:1099 org.apache.activemq:BrokerName=defaultBroker,Destination=Testing,Type=Queue MemoryLimit
```

but how can i set memorylimit?

I tried below:

```
java -jar cmdline-jmxclient-0.10.3.jar - localhost:1099 org.apache.activemq:BrokerName=defaultBroker,Destination=Testing,Type=Queue setMemoryLimit=300000`
```

**and failed as below.**

11/18/2011 11:56:28 -0800 org.archive.jmx.Client setMemoryLimit=300000: Operation setMemoryLimit not found.

Comment: Are you sure there is a set method on it?  Can you do it from jconsole?  If so then you should be able to show what method is being called and then duplicate the method name in the command line.

Comment: yes, i was able to do it with JConsole. that s why i wanted to do this via command line, so i can automate it.

Comment: how can i see on jconsole, what method was called? i see a gui. dont show me the method calls.

Comment: If you are using a java6+ jconsole, you open up a bean to show the Attributes and Operations.  If you click on the name of the bean you should see the `ObjectName` to use on the command line.  Then if you open the attributes list, the name of the attribute should have a corresponding get method.  If the value is colored blue then there should be a corresponding set method.

Comment: http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html there is an attribute for MemoryLimit, i just dont see the proper method to set it.

Comment: If the `MemoryLimit` is not blue in jconsole and if it doen't show up as a setter in the cmdline-jmxclient then it may not be settable.

Comment: it s blue but this client seems very old and looks like noone is maintaining it. no where to find anything about it.

Comment: Huh.  Send me mail at 256.com/gray/email/ and I'll get you a copy of my jmx command line client.  Much better.

Comment: The correct format is: `java -jar cmdline-jmxclient-0.10.3.jar - localhost:1099 org.apache.activemq:BrokerName=defaultBroker,Destination=Testing,Type=Queue MemoryLimit=300000`. Note that this client can only set non-primitive types, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit**

I'd recommend dropping that jmxclient and switching to:

> http://wiki.cyclopsgroup.org/jmxterm

It looks to be supported and better documented.  I suspect that it will work and give you access to the setters -- if they exist.

---

If the set method does exist then the following should work:

```
java -jar cmdline-jmxclient-0.10.3.jar - localhost:1099 \
    org.apache.activemq:BrokerName=defaultBroker,Destination=Testing,Type=Queue \
    setMemoryLimit=...
```

Here are the docs:

> http://crawler.archive.org/cmdline-jmxclient/

To find out which attributes are available for setting and getting, I'd use jconsole.  If you are using a Java6+ jconsole, you field click on the bean you want to get information from. That should show you the `ObjectName` to use on the command line. Then if you open the attributes list, the name of the attribute should have a corresponding get method. If the value is colored blue then there should be a corresponding set method.

For example, if you open up the `java.lang` folder in jconsole, you should be able to click on `ClassLoading`.  That shows you the `ObjectName` to use is `java.lang:type=ClassLoading`.  You can then do the following to list the various attributes and operations available:

```
java -jar cmdline-jmxclient-0.10.3.jar - localhost:1099 \
    java.lang:type=ClassLoading
```

You should see the getters and the setters.  Here's how you get the `Verbose` attribute:

```
java -jar cmdline-jmxclient-0.10.3.jar - localhost:1099 \
    java.lang:type=ClassLoading Verbose
```

For some reason my version cmdline-jmxclient does not know how to do `boolean` type so it doesn't show up as a setter.  If it did you should be able to do:

```
java -jar cmdline-jmxclient-0.10.3.jar - localhost:1099 \
    java.lang:type=ClassLoading setVerbose=true
```

Comment: sorry , forgot to mention in my question, i tried that and didnt work. see my edit please.